# Compiled Matlab code crashes when /clr is not selected

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio-2010, matlab

I'm wondering why the code I'm using with a compiled Matlab library crashes when a common language runtime is not selected.
For a minimal example, I've tried compiling the following Matlab function into a shared library:

```
function [volOut, volAvg]=testVarPass(volIn)
volOut=double(volIn);
volAvg=mean(volOut(:));
end
```

using the following call to mcc:
mcc -B csharedlib:mylib testVarPass.m

Next, I've set up a Visual Studios 2010 Console Project.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "matrix.h"
#include "mylib.h"
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    mxArray *vol_in;
    mxArray *vol_out;
    mxArray *vol_avg;
    mwSize dim_list[3];
    double *vol_avg_ptr;
    dim_list[0]=10;
    dim_list[1]=10;
    dim_list[2]=10;
    if( !mclInitializeApplication(NULL,0) ) { //initialize Matlab Compiler Runtime
        return -1; 
    } 
    if (!mylibInitialize()) //initialize library
    { 
        return -2; 
    }
    vol_in=mxCreateNumericArray(3,dim_list, mxINT16_CLASS, mxREAL);  //make a sample 3d array
    mlfTestVarPass(2, &vol_out, &vol_avg, vol_in); //crashes here
    vol_avg_ptr=mxGetPr(vol_avg);     
    /* Call the MCR and library termination functions */ 
    mylibTerminate(); 
    mclTerminateApplication();
    return 0;
}
```

If I build the project with Common Language Runtime Support set to: /clr...everything works fine.
If I build the project with Common Language Runtime Support set to: nothing...first, the debugger vomits many exceptions when mylibInitialize is called.  The most common are: varflowFailed, tffFailed, CryptoPP, jitCgFailed, and xsd_binder::MalformedDocumentError.  Second, the mlfTestVarPass call crashes with an access violation.

I, and a programmer I'm working with, are wondering why.

Other Information:
Windows 7
Visual Studio 2010, SP1
Windows SDK 7.1
Matlab 2013b

Answer (score 0):

The programmer I work with figured this out...

When /clr is selected, uninitialized pointers are set to NULL.
When /clr is not selected, uninitialized pointers are set to an arbitrary value by the debugger.  Then, when mlfTestVarPass is called, Matlab's memory management sees an arbitrary mxArray and tries to deallocate the unallocated memory.

This explains the crash, however, we still don't understand why there are so many first-chance exceptions.  It may simply reflect how Mathworks wrote their code.